# Is it possible to set a build discard option for jenkins github organisation builds?

Tags: jenkins

We have a jenkins setup with github organisation builds, meaning all github repos with a Jenkinsfile will automatically end up as jenkins jobs. This all works fine. The problem is that it seems like every github project needs to set their own build discarder option, and most don't. This means these builds are never being removed.

Is there a way to set a global build discarder policy for these kinds of multi-repo builds? The orphaned build strategy does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and there are a couple of strategies for [doing this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215549798-Best-Strategy-for-Disk-Space-Management-Clean-Up-Old-Builds?flash_digest=908c09edaeacea4b4ec564d50926b21f21b1da8d) at the global Jenkins master level.

However, that previous strategies involve affecting **all** jobs on the Jenkins server, not just in your Github organization.

My recommendation is to set an organization-level orphan discard number and then override that setting at the repo level in the builds where you want a more fine-grained discard policy.

You can do the latter like this in the Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  ...
  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10', artifactNumToKeepStr: '1'))
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Setting an organisation-level orphan discard doesn't work as one would hope. That's what prompted this question. It merely discards orphaned repositories and orphaned branches inside repositories. It does not discard builds inside active branches. So right now i probably have to ask all developers to add a snippet to their Jenkinsfile. Or perhaps just do it on the shell, but that seems a bit overkill.